# Ubuntu 22.04 second display freezes intermittently NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors

Sometimes my external monitor, which I connect to my laptop via HDMI, just freezes. It is detected by the display manager in settings and if I make a change to its settings and revert them back it unfreezes but after some work it freezes again.

I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile videocard. NVIDIA proprietary drivers are installed and updated (currently it's "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535").

I would like to find a permanent solution to my screen freezing issue because my temporary settings change doesn't work for too long and it's annoying to do it every 5-10 minutes.

EDIT: There are several threads in nvidia's developer forums regarding this issue. [External monitor freezes when using dedicated GPU](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/external-monitor-freezes-when-using-dedicated-gpu/265406/) probably being the best one to follow.

Comment: Have you tried another HDMI cable and/or monitor just to eliminate hardware as the issue?

Comment: @Terrance Hardware is not the issue since it works on Windows perfectly with the same setup. I have both Windows and Ubuntu installed on the same laptop.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1484560/edit) your question and add in some more details like possible applications that are running while you are seeing this freeze up?  Also, does it do the same freezing if you boot to a Live USB and run the Try Ubuntu?  Maybe get the output in a terminal of `free --si -h` or `uptime` that will show the CPU load averages.  Please add any more details you can give us to your question.

Comment: The reason I ask for this is that I do have a 1060 card in my system and I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with 3 monitors attached to it on 3 different types of connectors and I am not experiencing any types of lockups or freezes after 10-15 minutes.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am using Ubuntu 23.04 and NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3080 Ti Laptop. Any solution?

Comment: I also have this issue - Ubuntu 22.04, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 with Nvidia driver version: 535.129.03

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. Following the thread mentioned in the question ([External monitor freezes when using dedicated GPU](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/external-monitor-freezes-when-using-dedicated-gpu/265406)) the solution for now seems to be enabling the 'Performance Mode' for your GPU in the NVIDIA settings. It should avoid the freezing at the cost of higher power consumption. The issue should hopefully get fixed properly in a future driver update.

[Screenshot: Performance Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHMuO.png)

Comment: I haven't experienced this issue for a while now. Maybe recent driver update did fix it as you said.